# Activate Python 2.7

Tags: python, virtualenv, anaconda

**Environment**

- Default install of python 3.4 via Anaconada 3
- Installed in default directory of C:\Anaconda3
- Created 2.7 virtual environment

**Issue**

Using 'activate py27' and then typing command 'spyder' works perfectly.  My Spyder IDE launches in version 2.7.

However, if i 'activate py27' and then call a python script by using 'python C:\script_path_here' it runs the script in python 3.4.  Similarly, if i 'activate py27' and type 'python' it launches in 3.4.  Why does spyder work properly but not default python?

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Does `python2` work?

Comment: Nope, it returns 'python2' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Are you sure that Spyder is launched with python's version 2.7 ? How did you created your venv ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python 3.4 environment variable was taking precedence over the 2.7 because of the directory I was in. Even though 2.7 was activated.

Changing to the 'envs' directory changed the precedence and correctly booted the 2.7 instance.

Big thanks to [Matthew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/433829/matthew-plourde) for helping to solve the issue.

[image: Screen Shot]